# Amazon S3/Cloudfront bucket providing "Unable to check if <img> exists" error when uploading an asset

Tags: assets, craft4, s3, aws

I have just set up my first S3/CloudFront service to handle assets and it all seems to be connected right, but when I upload an asset into the volume that is stored on S3, I get this odd error in CraftCMS which I haven't been able to find many resources about:

[image: Screenshot of "Unable to check if exists" error]

This doesn't appear to be a permissions/policy error as this was a separate error I had in the process of putting this together. I have tried to upload different images in the hope the one I was trying was corrupt, but it appears to be happening with all.